# Beatbox: Possible to add condition to query when pulling SFDC data?

Tags: python, pandas, salesforce, beatbox

In Pandas, I want to pull Opportunity data with CreatedDate >= 1/1/2015.

Currently, I am extracting all Opportunity data before filtering for CreatedDate. Is it possible to optimize this process by adding the CreatedDate condition to the query?

**Current State:**

```
query_result = service.query("SELECT ID, CreatedDate FROM Opportunity")
records = query_result['records']
oppty = pd.DataFrame(records)

oppty = oppty[(oppty['CreatedDate'] >= '2015-01-01')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add the condition to the salesforce query, e.g.

SELECT ID, CreatedDate from Opportunity WHERE CreatedDate > 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z

As CreatedDate is a Date/Time field, you need to provide a full dateTime for the comparison value.

the [SOQL docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/) cover all these. There are also tools like [SoqlX](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/), [Workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench) etc that let you run add-hoc queries, these are useful for trying things out without having to run your full integration.